# Multiple parameters with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i am making a website. where i have a php script that takes care of serving the page based on what parameters it gets through a get request.

If someone types in `http://test.com/blog` it should be redirected to a php file, and it does. if someone types in `http://test.com/blog/test` it should be redirected to the same file with the parameter `test`. This does also work.

The thing i can´t figure out is, if someone types in `http://test.com/blog/test/something/something_else` it should be redirected to the script with `test/something/something_else` as a parameter. But it does only produce a 404 error.

Here is my htacces file:

```
    RewriteEngine  on

    RewriteRule    ^blog/?$    /home/blog/index.php    [NC,L]
    RewriteRule    ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    /home/blog/index.php?params=$1    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included the forward slash (`/`) in the regex group.

Change `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` to `([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)` or, better yet, `([\w-/]+)`. `\w` means 'match one or more alphanumeric character'.